# Can logstash's JDBC input plugin do multiple sql tasks?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc

Now there is a JDBC task read from db as

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_MAIN_HOST}/${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_page_size => 10000
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    jdbc_password => "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
    jdbc_user => "${MYSQL_USER}"
    schedule => "0 1 * * *"
    statement_filepath => "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/sql/select_posts.sql"
    tracking_column => "updated_at"
    tracking_column_type => "numeric"
    use_column_value => true
    last_run_metadata_path => "/usr/share/logstash/jdbc_last_run/select_posts_last_value"
  }
}
```

/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/sql/select_posts.sql

```
SELECT
  id,
  title,
  body
FROM posts
```

This task is heavy when the `body` item goes to very large data. So I want to remove it at the first search as:

```
SELECT
  id,
  title
FROM posts
```

Then get the IDs and use them to find `body` again.

```
SELECT
  body
FROM posts
WHERE id in (IDs)
```

To set to output target. Even update the output target is also okay.

So can logstash read statement by statement in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute two separate sql queries using logstash, you can do it as follows

- query1. sql

```
SELECT
  id,
  title
FROM posts
```

- query2.sql

```
SELECT
  body
FROM posts
WHERE id in (IDs)
```

- logstash.conf

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_MAIN_HOST}/${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_page_size => 10000
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    jdbc_password => "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
    jdbc_user => "${MYSQL_USER}"
    schedule => "0 1 * * *"
    statement_filepath => <PATH TO query1.sql>  -----query1.sql
    tracking_column => "updated_at"
    tracking_column_type => "numeric"
    use_column_value => true
    last_run_metadata_path => "/usr/share/logstash/jdbc_last_run/select_posts_last_value"
  }

 jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_MAIN_HOST}/${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_page_size => 10000
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    jdbc_password => "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
    jdbc_user => "${MYSQL_USER}"
    schedule => "0 1 * * *"
    statement_filepath => "<PATH TO query2.sql>"    -----query2.sql
    tracking_column => "updated_at"
    tracking_column_type => "numeric"
    use_column_value => true
    last_run_metadata_path => "/usr/share/logstash/jdbc_last_run/select_posts_last_value"
  }
}
```